# How to get key names from JSON using jq

Tags: json, shell, unix, key, jq

`curl http://testhost.test.com:8080/application/app/version | jq '.version' | jq '.[]'`

The above command outputs only the values as below:

```
"madireddy@test.com"

"2323"

"test"

"02-03-2014-13:41"

"application"
```

How can I get the key names instead like the below:

```
email

versionID

context

date

versionName
```

Answer (score 388, accepted):

To get the keys in the order they appear in the original JSON use:

```bash
jq 'keys_unsorted' file.json
```

If you want the keys sorted alphanumerically, you can use:

```bash
jq 'keys' file.json
```

Complete example

```bash
$ cat file.json
{ "Created-By" : "Apache Maven", "Build-Number" : "", "Archiver-Version" : "Plexus Archiver", "Build-Id" : "",  "Build-Tag" : "", "Built-By" : "cporter"}

$ jq 'keys_unsorted' file.json                                         
[
  "Created-By",
  "Build-Number",
  "Archiver-Version",
  "Build-Id",
  "Build-Tag",
  "Built-By"
]

$ jq 'keys' file.json
[
  "Archiver-Version",
  "Build-Id",
  "Build-Number",
  "Build-Tag",
  "Built-By",
  "Created-By"
]
```

Comment: This is great when an API returns you something gigantic and you have to scroll up to find the name of the field at the beginning of the object.

Comment: I wonder if there's an equivalent for only a sub-json object. It only works on the top-level object.

Answer (score 87):

To get the keys on a deeper node in a JSON:

```
echo '{"data": "1", "user": { "name": 2, "phone": 3 } }' | jq '.user | keys[]'
"name"
"phone"
```

Comment: This one is a bit better than the accepted answer, as it demonstrates how to use | within a jq expression, rather than piping output through several instances of jq

Answer (score 44):

You need to use `jq 'keys[]'`. For example:

```
echo '{"example1" : 1, "example2" : 2, "example3" : 3}' | jq 'keys[]'
```

Will output a line separated list:

```
"example1"
"example2"
"example3"
```

Answer (score 21):

In combination with the above answer, you want to ask jq for raw output, so your last filter should be eg.:

```
     cat input.json | jq -r 'keys'
```

From jq help:

```
     -r     output raw strings, not JSON texts;
```

Answer (score 14):

If your input is an array of objects,

```
[
  { 
    "a01" : { "name" : "A", "user" : "B" }
  },
  { 
    "a02" : { "name" : "C", "user" : "D" }
  }
]
```

try with:

```
jq '.[] | keys[]'
```

Answer (score 11):

To print keys on one line as csv:

```
echo '{"b":"2","a":"1"}' | jq -r 'keys | [ .[] | tostring ] | @csv'
```

Output:

```
"a","b"
```

For csv completeness ... to print values on one line as csv:

```
echo '{"b":"2","a":"1"}' | jq -rS . | jq -r '. | [ .[] | tostring ] | @csv'
```

Output:

```
"1","2"
```

Answer (score 11):

Oddly enough, the accepted answer doesn’t actually answer the Q exactly, so for reference, here is a solution that does:

```
$ jq -r 'keys_unsorted[]' file.json
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. I spend over 6 hours just on this issue. Thank you! You can also use a JSON varaible too using:  `declare -a MASTER_KEYS_LIST=($(jq -r 'keys_unsorted[]' <<< "${JSON_OBJECT_VAR}"))`

Comment: Yep, this is the only one that doesn't change the order of your keys. Though the `[]` seems unnecessary. This works for me `jq 'keys_unsorted' file.json`

Comment: @peak thanks for this proper solution, I edited the accepted answer to add `keys_unsorted` and made the example data show the difference (OP used sorted keys which hid the difference between keys and keys_unsorted)

Answer (score 7):

`echo '{"ab": 1, "cd": 2}' | jq -r 'keys[]'` prints all keys one key per line without quotes.

```
ab
cd
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of getting a Bash array with the example JSON given by @anubhava in his answer:

```sh
arr=($(jq --raw-output 'keys_unsorted | @sh' file.json))

echo ${arr[0]}    # 'Archiver-Version'
echo ${arr[1]}    # 'Build-Id'
echo ${arr[2]}    # 'Build-Jdk'
```