# Yq: retrieve object keys names

Tags: shell, yaml, jq, yq

I have a YAML file (docker-compose file in my case) that looks like this:

```
networks:
    foo:
      some_opts: "covfefe"
    bar:
      some_opts: "such wow"
services:
  apache:
    image: 'apache:1.0.0'
    restart: always
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:1.0.0'
    restart: always
  php:
    image: 'php'
    restart: always
```

I would like to extract the services name thanks to [`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), an equivalent of `jq` but for YAML, to have this output:

```
"apache"
"mysql"
"php"
```

Currently I can achieve it like this:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml | yq '.services' | yq 'keys[]'
"apache"
"mysql"
"php"
```

Even if it works, the double piped `yq` seems weird to me. I think I'm doing it wrong.

**Question:** Is there any way to achieve it with a single `yq` command ?

I tried this without success, taking inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118341/how-to-get-key-names-from-json-using-jq):

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml | yq '.services.keys[]'
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`keys` is a built-in function in `jq` when given an object, returns its keys in an array. So it is not actually apart of your yaml (not a property) which means you cannot do `services.keys`.

To get the keys you can do the following when using [Python yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

We will get the object of `services` in the first part then we pass it to `keys` which will return a list of keys based on a given object

```
cat docker-compose.yml | yq '.services | keys'
```

Or like this (*without cat and pipe*):

```
yq '.services | keys' docker-compose.yml
```

The output will be:

```
[
  "apache",
  "mysql",
  "php"
]
```

To get rid of the brackets:

```
yq '.services | keys[]' docker-compose.yml
```

The output:

```
"apache"
"mysql"
"php"
```

For more about details you can check [Builtin operators and functions](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) in `jq`. Note that `yq` is a wrapper for `jq` so the documentation of `jq` would be helpful as the help of `yq` recommends.

---

On [Go yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) you can do

```
yq e '.services | keys'
```

Comment: Thanks @Mostafa, this is what I was looking for. I was missing that point: `keys` is a built-in function not a property. Also thanks for the doc link :)

Comment: To make it work I had to write `yq eval '.services | keys' docker-compose.yml`

Comment: `yq -r '.services | keys | .[]'` will get you the flat list of services without a YAML list

Answer (score 8):

Since you just want to list the services from a docker-compose file you could achieve this with a docker-compose command.

```
docker-compose config --services
```

Not directly an answer to the question as it is not using yq but maybe it helps ;)

Comment: `docker-compose config --services` takes over 1 second to load for some reason. interestingly `ruby -e 'require "yaml"; puts YAML.load(File.read("docker-compose.yml"))["services"].keys'` completes in ~0.1s

Comment: while docker-compose config scans the config and might be helpful to check the final configuration that will be applied. 
In this case I would more stick on the solution from Mostafa Hussein 
`yq '.services | keys[]' docker-compose.yml`

Comment: i love this option. Pretty straightforward and it doesn't require `yq`